# Any open-souce software for me to manage big-data cluster including hadoop/hive/spark/?

Tags: hadoop, ambari, bigdata

I am looking for an open-source system for me to **manage my big-data cluster** which is composed of 50+ machines including components like hadoop, hdfs, hive, spark, oozie, hbase, zookeeper, kylin.
I want to **manage** them in a web system .The meaning of **"manage"** is :

1. I can **restart** the component one-by-one with only one click ,such
   as when I click the "restart" button ,the component zookeeper will
   be restarted one machine by another
2. I can **deploy** a component with only one click, such as when I
   deploy a new zookeeper , I can make a compiled zookeeper prepared in
   one machine ,then I click "deploy", it will deployed to all machines
   automatically.
3. I can **upgrade** a component with only one click ,such as when I
   want to update a zookeeper cluster, I can put the updated zookeeper
   in a machine ,then I click "update" ,then the updated zookeeper will
   override all the old version of zookeeper in other machines.

all in all , what I want is a management system for my big-data cluster like restart,deploy,upgrade,view the log ,modify the configuration and so on , or at least some of them .

I have considered **Ambari**, but it can only be used to deploy my whole system **from absolute scratch**, but my big-data cluster is already running for 1 years.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the end of goal of this one click functions? Are you looking at manually managing your cluster or do you plan to automate these actions based on incoming workloads?
A meta-scheduler will help you for the second one but you may need to develop your own one click functions to match your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Ambari is what you want. It's the only open source solution for managing hadoop stacks that meets your listed requirements. You are correct that it doesn't work with already provisioned clusters, this is because to achieve such a tight integration with all those services it must know how they were provisioned and where everything is and know what configurations exist for each. The only way Ambari will know that is if it was used to provision those services.

Investing the time to recreate your cluster with Ambari may feel like its painful but in the long run it will payoff due to the added ability to upgrade and manage services so easily going forward.

Comment: Great thanks for you big help.Two choices for me now : moving my system to a ambari one , or develop a system from scratch.I will evaluate both of them and make a final decision.